# How to read a small percentage of lines of a very large CSV. Pandas - time series - Large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, bigdata

I have a time series in a big text file.
That file is more than 4 GB.

As it is a time series, I would like to read only 1% of lines.

Desired minimalist example:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('super_size_file.log',
                      load_line_percentage = 1)
print(df)
```

desired output:

```
>line_number, value
 0,           654564
 100,         54654654
 200,         54
 300,         46546
 ...
```

I can't resample after loading, because it takes too much memory to load it in the first place.

I may want to load chunk by chunk and resample every chunk. But is seems inefficient to me.

Any ideas are welcome. ;)

Comment: `read_csv` has a `nrows` arg and `chunksize`, did you try any of these: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: You can run linux head command, and read it

`head super_size_file.log > small_sample.log`
or 
`head -n 1000 super_size_file.log > small_sample.log`

Comment: @EdChum: nrows load n first row. I want to load it all, but only 1 line out of 100... chunkzise is great, but it take time to load each chunk. ( 99% of it I do not want). But it's deffinitly my B plan.
@ sh.jeon: 'head' in linux seems the same as nrows. ( interesting btw, but same comment from my point of view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime I have to deal with a very large file, I ask "What would [Dask](https://dask.org/) do?".

Load the large file as a `dask.DataFrame`, convert the index to a column (workaround due to full index control not being available), and filter on that new column.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

nth_row = 100  # grab every nth row from the larger DataFrame
dask_df = dd.read_csv('super_size_file.log')  # assuming this file can be read by pd.read_csv
dask_df['df_index'] = dask_df.index
dask_df_smaller = dask_df[dask_df['df_index'] % nth_row == 0]

df_smaller = dask_df_smaller.compute()  # to execute the operations and return a pandas DataFrame
```

This will give you rows 0, 100, 200, etc. from the larger file. If you want to cut down the DataFrame to specific columns, do this before calling compute, i.e. `dask_df_smaller = dask_df_smaller[['Signal_1', 'Signal_2']]`. You can also call compute with the `scheduler='processes'` option to use all cores on your CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the number of rows you want to read when you use the **read_csv** pandas function. Here is what you could do :

```
import pandas as pd
# Select file 
infile = 'path/file'
number_of_lines = x
# Use nrows to choose number of rows
data = pd.read_csv(infile,, nrows = number_of_lines*0.01)
```

You can also use the chunksize option if you want to read the data chunk by chunk like you mentionned :

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Iterating through files chunk by chunk](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).
It contains an elegant description how to read a CSV file in chunks.

The basic idea is to pass *chunksize* parameter (No of rows per chunk).
Then, in a loop, you can read this file chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
# Select All From CSV File Where

import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("C:\\your_path\\test.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)

# If you only want to read rows 1,000,000 ... 1,999,999
read_csv(..., skiprows=1000000, nrows=999999)
```